# How to conditionally add an error to an Observable in RxDart?

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

Using a Dart StreamTransformer, I can evaluate a stream value and choose to emit it based on some condition (e.g. `sink.add(value)`), or add an error (e.g. `sink.addError('Enter a valid number')`).

How would I do best do this using RxDart's fluent operators?  I could use `.map` to evaluate the value and use `addError('message')` against the subject.  However, is there some better way?

Comment: I'm running up against the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Stream.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Stream/map.html) will forward thrown exceptions on as error events in the stream.

```
var result = values.map(
  (value) => someCondition(value) ? value : throw 'Enter a valid number ');
```

Comment: Thanks also for the link to the documentation.